# What does "Picadillo" mean

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms

I've heard expressions such as "He's had his picadillos" or "The Picadillos of his youth".

But I can't seem to find any definitions on google (Maybe I'm just spelling it wrong? haha), only examples of forum-members, and the like, using the phrases in abstract context that I am unable to extrapolate a definition.

Comment: Good catch of Google's normally reliable ability to help with spelling errors.

Comment: The word is spelled "peccadillo"

Comment: I suspect that the misspelling shows the baleful influence of [_Tiparillo_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiparillo) on innocent words of similar sound and inflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only imagine it comes from the Spanish word `pecadillo`, which means "small sin" or "minor sin". This would make sense in the examples you provided. Hope this helps!

Comment: Makes perfect sense in every context I've heard! Thanks, I'll accept this answer as soon as STackExchange's answer-accepting timer runs down hahah!

Comment: You mean http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/peccadilloes http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peccadilloes

Comment: @mplungjan Happy for the reference :) I indeed was hearing the Italian version "peccadiglio".

Comment: @mikethirteen I think your spelling is correct of the Spanish word - however the English loaner became peccadillo

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're thinking of the word "peccadillo".

From Google:

> **pec·ca·dil·lo** ˌpekəˈdilō noun
>
> a small, relatively unimportant offense or sin.
>
> Synonyms: misdemeanor, petty offense, indiscretion, lapse, misdeed
>
> *I'm sure we can overlook a few peccadilloes.*

Answer (score 0):

The Spanish is spelt "pecadillo" from "pecado" = sin and the , diminutive suffix "illo".

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about "picadillo" is a dish, mostly common in Central America. Are some vegetables turned into a hash and then cooked. I am not a native english speaker but I think that the literally traslate can be "chopped"
Homever if you are saying "pecadillo" is another word. It is the root of the word "Pecado" (sin) and the derogative suffix form of the word itself, that is "illo" when is masculine and if is femenine "illa" 
For make the word smaller you add the suffix "ito" and "ita"

Comment: The question is clearly about a misspelling.